# What does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan(\frac{1}{2^n})$ converge to?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I recently saw $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan(\frac{1}{n})$ diverges by bounding it by the harmonic series. I wondered if we had a geometric progression inside the function,   $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan(\frac{1}{2^n})$, if this series converges? If so, what does it converge to?

Comment: It converges, yes.  But there is no reason to think the sum has a nice closed form.

Comment: $0.9578884571$ approximately

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/651662/42969

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}{\arctan x\over x}=1$

Answer (score 0):

For the convergence, it suffices note that for any $x\ge 0$ we have $\arctan x\le x$ then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=1$$

and, as noticed, the series converges.

For its values, as noticed, there is not a closed form but we can give a good numerical estimation with few terms.

Comment: Why is the inequality true? I know the small angle approximation arctan(x)~x, but the Taylor series expansion is alternating so why do we know it's an upper bound arctan(x)<x?

Comment: @Mars Let consider $f(x)=\arctan x - x$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f’(x)<0$ for $x>0$.